# android studio 22.3 connect my phone crash - "Already resumed, but proposed with update -1"

Tags: android, crash

this is idea log  C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\log

```
2023-12-15 19:17:14,478 [ 446020]   INFO - #o.j.p.g.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio1/jbr
2023-12-15 19:17:24,114 [ 455656]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.adb.processnamemonitor.ProcessNameMonitorService - Adding C7Y4C19830000263
2023-12-15 19:17:24,188 [ 455730]   INFO - #com.android.adblib.impl.SyncSendHandler - device:serial-C7Y4C19830000263,sync:SEND - AdbInputFileChannel("C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\plugins\android\resources\process-tracker-agent\native\arm64-v8a\process-tracker") -> "/data/local/tmp/.studio/process-tracker"
2023-12-15 19:17:24,267 [ 455809]   INFO - STDERR - Exception in thread "Thread-146" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already resumed, but proposed with update CompletedExceptionally[java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already resumed, but proposed with update -1]
```

i can't do nothing to stop to crash

Comment: Sorry but your post is too short to understand what is going wrong. You should edit it and describe in detail what you are trying to do and the spes and commands you perform and what happens then. BTW the title indicates that the whole phone crashes, is this really true or does just an app crash?

Comment: thank you for your reply， I use andorid studio 2021.3.1 version,  is ok to connect any phone . but for some reason I want to update android studio.  then I install the latest android studio. after that ,  the new version couldn't connect any phone , when the usb line connect ,the andorid studio crashed